# OpenGL Timer Queries Result is always 0

Tags: opengl

I'd like to know in my application what's take time to render.
I tried to use Timer Queries but I always receive 0 as result.

Here is the code

```
    GLuint64        time = 0;
    GLuint          query;
    GLint           resultAvailable = 0;

    glGenQueries(1,&query);
    glBeginQuery(GL_TIME_ELAPSED,query);
    myRenderingCode();
    glEndQuery(GL_TIME_ELAPSED)

    while (!resultAvailable) {
            glGetQueryObjectiv(query, GL_QUERY_RESULT_AVAILABLE, &resultAvailable);
    }


    glGetQueryObjectui64v(query, GL_QUERY_RESULT,&time);
    glDeleteQueries(1,&query);
```

I'm on Mac OSX 10.9 with "NVIDIA Corporation NVIDIA GeForce GT 650M OpenGL Engine 4.1"
Does anyone know why "time" is always set to 0?